# I am trying to use search product from DB, in nodejs but the product is not getting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, search

These are the products in MongoDB :(example)

```
product><<<<< [
     {
        _id: new ObjectId("62873c15c7becd09b1377fd8"),
        Name: 'pixel 6',
        Category: 'smart Phone',
        Price: '60000',
        Description: 'Note that to perform a smart search, DataTables uses regular expressions, so if enable regular expressions using the second parameter to this method, you will likely want to disable smart searching as the two regular expressions might otherwise conflict and cause unexpected results.',
        Brand: 'Google'
      },
      {
        _id: new ObjectId("628795e6a55d421aaca788cb"),
        Name: 'iphone 11   pro ',
        Category: 'smartphone',
        Price: '100000',
        Brand: 'apple',
        Description: 'something'
      }

]
```

I am trying to search product from DB, in nodejs but the product is not getting???
here  is my code:
this is my search container in my header

> > > user-header.hbs

```
<div class="search-container">
        <form class="form-inline" action="/search" method="get">
          <input class="search-input" id="search-box" type=" search" placeholder="Search..." name="searchTerm"
            aria-label="Search" />
        </form>
      </div>
```

> > > user.js

```
// GET: search box
router.get("/search",async (req, res) => {
   try {
      let searchTerm = req.body.searchTerm;
      let user = req.session.user;
      let product= await  productHelpers.getAllProducts({Name:{ $search: searchTerm,$options: "i", $diacriticSensitive: true }});
      res.render('user/search',{product,user});
      console.log('searchTerm>',searchTerm)
      console.log('products>',product)
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send({message: error.message || "Error Occured" });
      res.redirect("/"); 
    } 
 });
```

> > > user-helpers.js
> > > from user-helpers geting all products fron collections

```
  getAllProducts:()=>{ 

        return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
             let products=await db.get().collection(collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION).find().toArray()
             resolve(products)
        })
     },
```

> > > search.hbs
> > > Search result not getting

```
<h1 class="pb-4">Search Results</h1>

<div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-lg-5 g-2 g-lg-3">
  <a href="/" class="col text-center category__link">
    <div class="category__img category__img--large shadow">
      <img src="/product-images/{{product._id}}.jpg" alt="{{product.Name}}" loading="lazy">
    </div>
    <div class="pt-1">
      {{products.Name}} </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

my Assumption in user.js something wrong with the code!

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess!

- The name of the field you want to search is "Name"?
- If so! then have you created text index in the collection on the "Name"
  field?
- And shouldn't the syntax be like `{$text: { $search: searchTerm }}`